# OS X script based on IP

Tags: macos

I have a Synology DS212J NAS. I want to store all my work from eclipse and netbeans on the NAS.

And just use the network location as the workspace.

Its working fine, on my stationary windows PC. Since I do not move it. But since my router does not have any loopback, it does not work with my mac since I am moving it all the time.

When I am at home I can only use the internal IP to connect to the NAS.
When I am out I have to use the external IP to connect to the NAS.

I am very new to OS X. But is it possible to create some kind of script that connect to the server depending on the IP I am on? What should i be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a loopback on your router but if your router supports reverse nat you should be able to achieve what you want by setting up the reserve nat and configuring your server connection to your public address so that you have only one connection and the router will do the rest for you.